# javascript onclick object.method is not a function

Tags: javascript, object

I have created an object in javascript:

```
function Controller() {
    this.REST_URL = "http://localhost:8081";
    this.WS_URL = "ws://localhost:8080/o/sikomevents";
    this.clientState = new ClientState();
    this.wsIsConnected = false;
    //other fields
}

// other methods...

Controller.prototype.onAgentSet = function (event) {
    this.loginUserAndSubscribe($("#agent").val());
};
```

From html i want to call `onAgentSet`. Here is html:

```
<div >
    <div >
        <div>
            <div class="agent">
                <span class="s-lbl">Agent:</span>
                <input id="agent" type="text"/>
                <button onclick="controller.onAgentSet(event)" class="agent-btn" title="Agent wechseln"> <#-- remove class disabled if number typed in -->
                    <i class="material-icons">send</i>
                </button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var controller= new Controller();
</script>
```

I want call onAgentSet if button is clicked on the controller object but javascript throws error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: controller.onAgentSet is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):410)
```

I hope it is a simple syntax error. What is wrong here? In browser js console i can see the controller object with its methods but it seem to have no methods?!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It just complains that $ is not set because I haven't loaded jQuery.

Comment: Works for me (except for jQuery). Have you checked the error log in the console for any other problems? If there are errors in the script that defines `Controller` or its prototype, then that script won't finish executing. This can lead to `onAgentSet` not being defined on `Controller.protoype`.

Comment: Is your `Controller` declaration and script being loaded before or after your `var controller...` script?

Comment: I have tried your code and found no problem.

Comment: what happens if you call `controller.onAgentSet()` from just below your `var controller....`?

Comment: What is logged if you instead have this: `onclick="console.log(controller.onAgentSet)"`?

Comment: thanks for your hints. al js files are loaded in header of html and are present. i thought the script part (setting var controller) at the and sould be executed at the end?! Is this good? How to fix is, what is a better pattern here?